# convert regular expression to antlr regular expression format

Tags: regex, antlr

I have the following regular expression which shows multi line string. It starts with """ (3 double quotations) and ends with it """ too. How can I convert it to ANTLR regular expression? I know that ANTLR does not have lookahead, lookbehind and non-capturing groups as they have been used in this regex:

STRING :

```
(\"\"\"[^\"\\\\]*(?:(?:\\\\.|\"(?!\"\"))[^\"\\\\]*)*\"\"\")|(\"[^\"\\\\]*(?:\\\\.[^\"\\\\]*)*\")
```

Thank you.

Comment: If ANTLR supports back references, wouldn't this - `("(""|)(\\.|[\s\S])*?"\2)` - achieve what you're trying to do? [Check it out here at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/yF5fR0/2) (of course with added escapes)

Comment: I forgot to mention that the second part of the regex (after  bar | ) is for one line string that starts and ends with double quotations.

Comment: Rion: Antlr is giving me error on \2

Comment: Double quotes is handled by that regex as well. Check the demo.

Comment: ANTLR doesn't support regular expressions. It's not clear what you actually want. If you want grammar rules to match e.g. triple quoted strings and single quoted strings you would write them in separate rules, not in such an unreadable regex string.

Comment: @MikeLischke This regular expression is supposed to present strings in Notation3 language. I have received this regular expression from a Notation 3 parser and asked to convert it to a grammar rule (or token). strings in here can be multi line (triple quoted) or single line (double quoted).

Comment: @ClasG how can I write it without backreferencing?

Answer (score 0):

If ANTLR supports back references, try this:

```
("(""|)(\\.|[\s\S])*?"\2)
```

(of course with added escapes)

It handles both single, and triple "double-quotes".

[Check it out here at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/yF5fR0/2).